# Disable javascript in a site that you are framing

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Would it be possible to disable javascript in a website that you are trying to frame? If that website is trying to bust your framing attempts, could you essentially disarm all of their javascript completely, even if this means that the user will have to interact with the site without javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. If you are loading it in a frame or iframe there is no way to specify "load this website but don't enable javascript in its frame".

You might be able to proxy it and strip the js out: bad choice but probably your best option.

Answer (score 4):

That should not be possible, for several reasons. You can't enable/disable JavaScript at all from inside a page, other than to simply not use it, and you can't affect what's going on in pages loaded from different domains.

"Frame busting" is something sites do to protect themselves from sites like the one you're describing :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this server side by fetching the site and removing all of their script tags, then sending that to the user instead of a direct connection. But that could get very complicated if you needed to use cookies or something like that.

There is no way to do it client side because browsers prevent xss. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting